# PrimeFaces TabView - index of closing tab inside confirm dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is it possible in PrimeFaces 3.5 to open confirm dialog while closing tab, which was dynamically genereted? And while closing this tab the dialog should say which particular tab i want to close.

I've tried to use
`<p:ajax event="onTabClose" listener="#{myBean.closeTab}" />` - with this expression I can get the closing tab inside my listener and also I can open dialog using `onstart=myDialog.show()` inside that expression but always when I click 'x' on tab it will close regardless the confirm dialog.

So I've found `<p:tabView onTabClose="">` - here I can do what I want using `return confirm('Are you sure?')` (Can I create my own dialog here that will return 'true/false' and waiting for clicking 'yes/no'?).

But the problem is that I can't get the closing tab index regardless which metod I choose to show dialog.

When I use (tabList is a `List<Integer>`):

```
<p:tabView var="tab" value="#{myBean.tabList}" 
    onTabClose="return confirm('You are closing tab number #{tab}')" />

    <p:tab title="#{tab}" closable="true">
        <h:outputText value="#{Tab number #{tab}}" />
    </p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

everything are working correctly without dialog. It always show tab number 1!

So... is it possible to fix that? Or is there any other solution for this issue?